# Power connector for a HPA

Tags: power-supply, dc-power

I've got two Kuhne's HPAs rated at 12V, 10Amps. The HPAs have power connectors circled in blue. Is there a specific jumper with a compatible head that I could plug directly into this connector? I'm trying to avoid soldering if possible.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a feedthrough capacitor, it helps to filter the power and control lines entering the enclosure. It will have some capacitance to the body, and probably a small ferrite bead around the conductor.

You need to solder a wire to it.

But remember it's just the copper leg of a component, it's not very strong! The ground lug next to it may provide some strain relief, otherwise put a screw into the heatsink below it. If you pull the wire and snap it off, it will be a pain to repair.

Do it like this [own work]:
[image]

and not like this [apologies to [VK6UU]](https://www.vk6uu.id.au/Repeater-Project.html):
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I've seen these before, and they need to be soldered.

What you have is a solder-type feedthrough capacitor with a solder-type ground lug next to it.

Answer (score 0):

These appear to be expensive EMI feedthru attenuators of one type.

https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/96/tusod00051_5-2264834.pdf

Avoiding soldering may be less than reliable from oxidation.